What is an feasible atmospheric pressure for plants and humans on Mars?
On Earth plants can grow at an atmospheric pressure of around 5 psi (0.34 bar) with supplemental carbon dioxide. On Mars, the carbon dioxide would also be naturally concentrated underground.
What is a minimum safe depth on Mars or safe pressure where both plants and humans can grow, oxygen aside?
related: Pressurizing Ice on Mars

Your title and the body of your question ask 2 different things. I expect the minimum safe depth and the ideal pressure are quite different.

Humans can live (not sure why you wrote "grow"), oxygen aside at 61.8 millibars (about 0.9 PSI) the Armstrong Limit. As for plants, it really depends on the type of plant. This Quasi-Plant can survive in Mars-like conditions (source) while others like rye grass can survive at 70 millibars (about 1 PSI) (source), Arabidopsis thaliana can survive at 100 millibars (about 1.45 PSI) (source). I could keep going. As I have not found any study showing plants surviving under 61.8 millibars, I think it really depends what plant you select.
In order to reach 61.8 millibars (roughly 10 times the atmospheric pressure on Mars), and using the same formula as on your other question, you would need to dig 33,000 meters (108,500 feet) deep (give or take a few feet). You can use that formula to plug in the necessary depth for whatever plant as well.

Humans can not live at the Armstrong limit. The vapor pressure of water at 37 °C is 6.3 kPa. If the air pressure is 6.3 kPa too, the lungs will be filled with pure water vapor and no oxygen at all. "At the summit of Mount Everest, 8,848 metres (29,029 ft), where the total atmospheric pressure is 33.7 kPa, oxygen still constitutes 21% of the atmosphere but its partial pressure is only 7.1 kPa (i.e. 21% of 33.7 kPa = 7.1 kPa)"

Is it the case that Armstrong limit the start of where you die then, or am I totally wrong?@Uwe

See this text.

The Armstrong limit is at a height of about 19 km. But to survive breathing pure oxygen without a pressure suit and a sealed face mask you should be below 11.9 km. Humans have survived for 2 years at 5,950 m breathing pure air with 21 % oxygen. The highest permanent settlement known, La Rinconada, is at 5,100 m

@Uwe remember the oxygen aside part. What happens at 11.9 km is hypoxia.

@phil1008 I think said text is irrelevant, see the above comment

"oxygen aside" is doing a lot of heavy lifting in this Q/A pair, to the degree that it's not really accurate/realistic

An answer on a Q&A site should answer the question, should it not? I agree it is a weird constraint causing some weird results, though.@fyrepenguin

Live is very, very short at the Armstrong limit. With or without oxygen supply does not matter, no oxygen is present in the alveoli of the lungs and no oxygen is transferred to the blood. The complete absence of oxygen supply is referred to as anoxia. The pressure is not safe, it is lethal within a few minutes.

If you somehow, magically, did not need oxygen (ie. oxygen aside), then you would survive there, no?@Uwe

The Armstrong limit is the vapor pressure of water at 37 °C. There is no information if it is possible to survive at this limit and how long. Nothing about safe or unsafe.
